# PHP - Mysqli Select * From not returning data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to select all values in every column of my database using a Mysqli Select * From statement. However whenever I try to make the sql, it tells me that i am connecting to the database but I it is not returning any data when I know that there is data in the database. Here is my php code `

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
 $response = array();


$host = "127.0.0.1"; //server
$db = "database"; //database name
$user = "root"; //dabases user name
$pwd = "password"; //password

// get all products from products table

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Profiles");

if($result)
{
    echo("Contacted Database. ");   
}

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
  //Do stuff
}
else
{
 echo("No data found");
}

?>`
```

What I am getting from this code is `Contacted database. No data found`. However in phpmyadmin i see that I have data inside the database.

Comment: You're mixing APIs with `mysql_num_rows` use `mysqli_num_rows` - this isn't *gin & tonic*

Comment: @AbraCadaver I love "comments", they're just as effective as "answers" *per se*, yet take up less room then a can of worms. ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- quite possibly one of the best comparisons I've ever seen on Stackoverflow. +1 :)

Comment: @War10ck Thanks. My "*rum & coke*" version ran dry a while ago ;)

Comment: *groan* - [typo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315244/php-mysqli-select-from-not-returning-data#comment39459885_25315244) "than", not "then".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` calls. NONE of the PHP database libraries are interchangeable like that, even if they are talking to the same DB server.

You established your connection via `mysqli` (note the **i**), so use ONLY the `mysqli` functions.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysql_num_rows()` when you should be using `mysqli_num_rows()`.  Don't mix the `mysql` functions with the `mysqli` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the mysql_num_rows to mysqli_num_rows since you have used mysqli in the connect and query calls.